# CodeIgniter with Socket.io, Err: Fail to load resource

Tags: php, codeigniter, socket.io, livechat

Setup

- OS: Windows
- browser: Chrome
- socket.io version: 2.1.0
- CodeIgniter: 3

Hi, i'm trying to include the tutorial from web socket into my codeIgniter project.

But when i'm implement exact the same way i got the error "Fail to load resource: ... socket.io.js"

But if i try to access socket.io.js with this "localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js" URL it was able to access.

Since codeigniter will only run url like this "localhost/ci_test/chat", is there any way to overcome this issue or there is any proper tutorial for implement socket.io into CodeIgniter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well maybe u cn find this links interesting..
https://github.com/ericterpstra/ci_sock
----------
https://github.com/syifandimulyanto/codeigniter-socket.io

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with this :-

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
```

And modify socket at your display page.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```